# Wind power and tikz force

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a little symbol for a wind power (éolienne) but I'm not an artist ;-)
If any Leonado da Vinci or Picasso here could improve my try, I will be very glad.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw (0,0)--(280:.7)--(260:.7)--cycle ;
    \draw[very thick] (0,0)--(90:.4) ;
    \draw[very thick] (0,0)--(210:.4) ;
    \draw[very thick] (0,0)--(330:.4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't know about artistry, but here are three variations. This uses the latest PGF release for the `pic` handler but it isn't essential: the code inside the `pic` can be copied and used outside as long as `#1` is replaced with a number from `1` to `3`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
wind turbine/.pic={
  \tikzset{path/.style={fill, draw=white, ultra thick, line join=round}}
  \path [path] 
    (-.25,0) arc (180:360:.25 and .0625) -- (.0625,3) -- (-.0625,3) -- cycle;
  \foreach \i in {90, 210, 330}{
    \ifcase#1
    \or
      \path [path, shift=(90:3), rotate=\i] 
        (.5,-.1875) arc (270:90:.5 and .1875) arc (90:-90:1.5 and .1875);
    \or
      \path [path, shift=(90:3), rotate=\i] 
        (0,0.125) -- (2,0.125) -- (2,0) -- (0.5,-0.375) -- cycle;
    \or
      \path [path, shift=(90:3), rotate=\i]
        (0,-0.125) arc (180:0:1 and 0.125) -- ++(0,0.125) arc (0:180:1 and 0.25) -- cycle;
    \fi
  }
  \path [path] (0,3) circle [radius=.25];
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
  (0,0) pic {wind turbine=1}
  (4,0) pic {wind turbine=2}
  (8,0) pic {wind turbine=3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's. As I need 13 wind turbines positionned in a quater of circle, I add a little random angle for the positionning of the blades.   \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rand}{(rand*60 + 1) - 30} ;
  \foreach \i in {90, 210, 330}{
    \ifcase#1
    \or
      \path [path, shift=(90:3), rotate=\i+\Rand] ...

Comment: Out of curiosity: what for? "13 wind turbines positioned in a quarter of circle" sounds a bit... strange. ;)

Comment: To see how it will look in my garden ;-) more seriously it's for a concrete math exercice. There is an area around the wind turbines forbiden for navigation. Children have to calculate the surface of this area.

Comment: @mbork If you want to see what its looks like. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173569/tikz-pic-parameter

Comment: Nice exercice, I'll steal it ;-)

Comment: @remjg on va faire des échanges ?

Comment: Please stick to English, guys.

Comment: @Mark Wilbrow; I can't run your code...I get an error: undefined control sequence.\end{tikzpicture}. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @KKK the code still compiles for me as is. I guess it is a problem with your TeX distribution.