# Recommended tools for vector drawing

Tags: technical-drawing

I would like to draw a wind turbine to demonstrate the coordinate systems used  in my calculations. A similar one as follows

[image]

However I am wondering which tool would fit for this. I am beginner in tikz, therefore one solution would be to draw in an external tool which can export into tikz or pdf. Can anybody suggest one?

Comment: Inkscape is the tool for such things. Later if you want to be with the cool gang, you can import it to TikZ.

Comment: If you want to be with the lazy gang, you can copy Mark Wibrow: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173562

Comment: After some search and software tests find ipe a very easy drawing tool.

Answer (score 3):

A list of drawing tools that can export TikZ code is maintained on the TeXExample site.

http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/#tools-that-generate-pgftikz-code

Most of the tools mentioned are either some form of conversion script, or a stand-alone graphics editor.  Most of the graphics editor tools can export to PDF.