# How to draw a propeller with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the propeller, which is mixing the water in the pool.In attached file you can see my drawing. How can I develop this drawing?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 10pt] (-0.75,0.5) -- (-0.75,-2.75) --
    (3.0, -2.75) -- (3.0,0.5);
\draw[join=round, line width = 5pt, color = gray!25] (-0.75,0.42) --
    (-0.75,-2.75) -- (3.0, -2.75) -- (3.0,0.42);
\draw[join=round, line width = 10pt] (-1.5,-2.75) -- (-0.85,-2.75) ;
\draw[join=round, line width = 5pt, color = gray!25] (-1.5,-2.75) -- (-0.7,-2.75) ;
\draw[join=round, line width = 10pt] (3.10,-2.75) -- (3.75,-2.75) ;
\draw[join=round, line width = 5pt, color = gray!25] (3.00,-2.75) -- (3.75,-2.75) ;
\fill[gray!40!white] (-0.57,-2.57) rectangle (2.83,0.0);
\draw[rounded corners=2pt,fill=black, ultra thick] (0.8,-0.5) -- (2,-0.4) -- (2,-0.6) -- cycle;
\draw[rounded corners=2pt,fill=black, ultra thick] (1.2,-0.5) -- (0,-0.4) -- (0,-0.6) -- cycle;
\draw[join = round, ultra thick] (1,-0.50) -- (1,2.5);
\draw[-latex,thin](-1.5,-1.50)node[above,scale=1.0]{\scriptsize{$25^{\circ}C$}} to[out=-80,in=150] (-1.5,-2.70);
\draw[-latex,thin](2.0,1.0)node[above,scale=1.0]{\scriptsize{$90^{\circ}C$}} to[out=-80,in=100] (2.0,0.00);
\draw[-stealth,thin](0.75,1.25) to[out=-80,in=-120] (1.25,1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: what does a propeller look like?

Comment: @percusse https://www.google.fr/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=propeller&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=z-nvVuPKDrTF8AfIgIaoBw

Comment: @flav then OP will come and say *oh is it possible to draw it from the side view?* and then endless fun... ;)

Comment: @percusse What is OP ?

Comment: @flav Original Poster

Comment: Related: [Wind power and tikz force](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173562)

Comment: Related: [Draw an aircraft with Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114783/5764)

Comment: Using 'controls' will help you. From what I have in store : 
% agitation
\begin{scope}[ultra thick, black]
\draw (30,85) -- (30,35);
\draw[fill=black] (30,35) .. controls (32,36) and (34,37) .. (35,35) ..
   controls (34,33) and (32,34) .. (30,35);
\draw[fill=black] (30,35) .. controls (28,36) and (26,37) .. (25,35) ..
   controls (26,33) and (28,34) .. (30,35);
\end{scope}

Comment: I think that the OP gave some code and that he only wants a better shape for the drawing of the propeller part. I drew this kind of scheme before as a chemist (or chemical engineer). If the question is reopen I could get the opportunity to share some simple code with him

Comment: @DRi Probably those comments might have been responding to the original question which didn't include the code? In any case, it is now reopened, so you could now post your answer.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for reopening the question and giving me the opportunity to provide an answer.

Comment: @DRi I had nothing to do with reopening it ;).

Answer (score 1):

Using 'controls' and replacing only the two lines (instead of '\draw[rounded corners=2pt,fill=black, ultra thick]...') related to the propeller drawing :

```
\draw[fill=black] (1,-0.5) .. controls (1.4,-0.4) and (1.8,-0.3) .. (2,-0.5) .. controls (1.8,-0.7) and (1.4,-0.6) .. (1,-0.5);
\draw[fill=black] (1,-0.5) .. controls (1.4,-0.4) and (1.8,-0.3) .. (2,-0.5) .. controls (1.8,-0.7) and (1.4,-0.6) .. (1,-0.5);
```

will give you a nicer shape !
By the way, *propeller* is probably not the word you want to use, may I suggest *stirring blades* or *stirring impeller* instead.